# « Combien de fois devra-t-on / doit-on ... ? »: Whether to use the future or the present?

Tags: temps-grammatical

> "How many times ***do*** we ***have to*** go over this?"
>
> »Wie oft ***müssen*** wir es noch durchkauen?«

At least in English and German, the same idea is usually rendered in the present tense. But for a reason I can't quite put my finger on, I find myself tempted to go for the future in French. Which makes me wonder which tense is actually more commonly used with « combien de fois »?

> « Combien de fois ***devra***-t-on revenir là-dessus ? »
>
> or: « Combien de fois ***doit***-on revenir là-dessus ? »

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans cette phrase l'emploi du futur n'est pas lié à « combien de fois » mais au sentiment d'indignation exprimé par le locuteur.  Notons qu'on pourrait avoir un point d'exclamation à la place du point d'interrogation.

Deux exemples de la vie courante :

- La mère à son enfant :

  > Combien de fois faudra-t-il que je te répète de t'essuyer les pieds avant d'entrer !

  L'anglais et l'allemand utiliseraient plus volontiers le présent dans ce cas.
- Une exclamation que l'on entend souvent pour exprimer la surprise mêlée d'indignation.

  > On aura tout vu !

  Quelques traductions données par Reverso, [en anglais](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-english/l%C3%A0%2C+on+aura+tout+vu), [en allemand](http://context.reverso.net/translation/french-german/on+aura+tout+vu). Dans la plupart des cas emploi du passé pour rendre cette expression)

*Le bon usage* (Grevisse, 10<sup>e</sup> édition, VII 733)

> Le futur simple s'emploie aussi, dans les phrases exclamatives, pour exprimer un fait présent contre lequel on s'indigne en le considérant dans le futur.

La [BDLQ](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4127) :

> On peut aussi traduire l'indignation ou la protestation avec le futur, généralement dans une phrase interrogative ou exclamative.

Un exemple commenté tiré d'un article *Temps verbal et énonciation. Le conditionnel et le futur en français* (Cahier de praxématique, 56/2011)

> Le perfide ayant fait tout le tour du rempart, / Et vu chacun en sentinelle, / S’écria : « Quoi ! Ces gens se moqueront de moi ! / Eux seuls seront exempts de la commune loi ! Non, par tous les dieux ! non. Il accomplit son dire »
>   (La Fontaine, Fables, XII, 18, [*Le Renard et les poulets d’Inde*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=XFre1c0KNWUC&pg=PA123&lpg=PA123&dq=%22Quoi%20!%20Ces%20gens%20se%20moqueront%20de%20moi%20!%20/%20Eux%20seuls%20seront%20exempts%20de%20la%20commune%20loi%20!%20Non,%20par%20tous%20les%20dieux%20!%20non.%22&source=bl&ots=Zu7L_8B_3-&sig=s2qlZV60n3fhjYFp7g5IjJnMVPY&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2ovCduejUAhWOK1AKHUtiDVEQ6AEILjAC#v=onepage&q=%22Quoi%20!%20Ces%20gens%20se%20moqueront%20de%20moi%20!%20%2F%20Eux%20seuls%20seront%20exempts%20de%20la%20commune%20loi%20!%20Non%2C%20par%20tous%20les%20dieux%20!%20non.%22&f=false))
>   [...]
>   lorsque le renard s’écrie : « Quoi ! Ces gens se moqueront de moi ! », il pense que les dindons sont en train de se moquer de lui : on peut remplacer le futur par un présent : *Quoi ! ces gens se moquent de moi !* En actualisant au futur ce procès contemporain de son énonciation, le locuteur-énonciateur en récuse fictivement la réalité en le rejetant dans le monde du non encore réalisé : le futur, ce qui produit résultativement l’effet de sens d’indignation.

Le futur a d'autres valeurs modales, qui sont parfois aussi exprimées par un futur en anglais (atténuation de l'expression d'un ordre, vérité générale par exemple). Il ne faut donc pas généraliser sur cet emploi particulier du futur en français.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see a significant difference with English here:

> *Combien de fois **devra**-t-on revenir là-dessus ?*

→ How many times **will** we have to go over this?

> *Combien de fois **doit**-t-on revenir là-dessus ?*

→ How many times **do** we have to go over this?
→ How many times **must** we have to go over this?